# Illustrator: how to only export artwork inside the artboard and ignore what falls outside

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, export, artboard, canvas

I need to export what I created to a jpeg for print.  The image you see below was created in a new file by first creating a 3.5 x 2.5 file which automatically made a white canvas. I made my design ON THAT WHITE CANVAS. You can see the baseball falls off of that canvas. When I go to save I do not want that extra baseball fall off to be saved. I want ONLY what I designed on the white canvas to be saved.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you must use JPG:

- Go to 'File → Export'
- Choose 'JPG' from the 'Type' dropdown menu
- Tick 'Use Artboards' (this excludes the fall off)
- Click 'Save'
- Since you mentioned needing this for print, choose CMYK with the largest 'Quality' and 300dpi 'Resolution'

Note: for printing purposes a PDF might work better. In which case you should use 'Save as' and choose PDF format.

Comment: Saved me, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add an artboard (or other cropping criteria) size clipping mask (rectangle) just before you export as JPG. Release the mask when it is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

check this out, it will export and crop the artwork of each layer, instead of artboard. Works very well for me. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YEgoEsu4Vk)
[image]

Comment: It seems that you misunderstand the question. The OP wants to export the artboard without anything that lies outside, not to export the artwork only like explained in the video. Besides that please don't just post a link as an answer, but instead explain the process in your own words. That link will eventually stop working and your answer won't make sense anymore.